# Getting Error message "RegistrationPO is not a constructor" on log using Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

When i am executing my spec file(given below) ,I am getting the error message "RegistrationPO is not a constructor" ,Plz help me to solve my query.Thanks in advance.

```
//Registration_spec//

'use strict';
var FunLib = require('/Users/acer/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/FFAutomation/Function_Lib.js'); //Write the location of your javascript file
var RegistrationPO = require('/Users/acer/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/FFAutomation/Registration_PO.js'); //Write the location of your javascript file
var testData = require('./FFtestdata_Dev_p.json');

describe('Registration: ', function() {

    var FuncLib;
    var Registration;
    var URL;
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

    FuncLib = new FunLib();
    Registration = new RegistrationPO();

    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    });


    //Scenario 1: Open browser :working
    it('1-Open the web browser',function(){
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get('Http://dev.forfirm.com:3000');
        browser.sleep(200000);

    });

});
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of the file `RegistrationPO` also ...

Answer (score 0):

```
var FunLib = require('/Users/acer/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/FFAutomation/Function_Lib.js'); //Write the location of your javascript file
var RegistrationPO = require('/Users/acer/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/FFAutomation/Registration_PO.js'); //Write the location of your javascript file
```

Why do you trying to find your pageObjects in node_modules/protractor?
With this you will lose everything on every node_modules reinstall.

I believe this is the reason why you getting errors - you cant import, because file does not exist there

Create more plain structure, something like

```
   node_modules/...all your dependencies will be installed here
   utils/Function_Lib.js
   pageobjects/Registration_PO.js
   specs/registration.spec.js
   package.json
   protractor.config.js
```

Then your imports in `specs/registration.spec.js` will be something like this:

```
var FunLib = require('../utils/Function_Lib.js');
var RegistrationPO = require('../pageobjects/Registration_PO.js');
```

Also check what you are exporting in Registration_PO.js and Function_Lib.js